# How to use jquery autocompleter with simple json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete function with serviceUrl like this -

```
$('#locationsDiv').autocomplete({
            serviceUrl : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pages/getLocationList.do',
            paramName : "value",
            delimiter : ",",
            transformResult : function(response) {
                return {
                    //must convert json to javascript object before process
                    suggestions : $.map($.parseJSON(response), function(key,value) {
                        return {
                            value : key,
                            data : value
                        };
                    })
                };
            }
        });
```

in response of serviceUrl i got this response  -

```
{"1":"jaipur","2":"Amer","3":"Gurgaon"}
```

this json is coming from this hashmap -

```
HashMap<String, String> locationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        locationMap.put("1", "Jaipur");
        locationMap.put("2", "Ajmer");
        locationMap.put("3", "Kolkata");
        locationMap.put("4", "Raipur");
        locationMap.put("5", "Rajasthan");
```

when i using this autocompleter, all results are coming for any search.
 And i am not sure that for this json what `paramName` should be sent for filter result ?